# Can we use several independent clauses to express an idea of conditional without too much limitation?

Tags: syntax, list-of-languages, conditionals

In English, generally speaking, an idea of conditional is expressed by a sentence with a dependent clause (and usually with the conjunction "if"):

- If it rains, the picnic will be cancelled.

The dependent clause can be a non-finite clause:

- Weather permitting, we will go there on foot.

In addition, being expressed by a relative clause is also possible:

- Anyone who should do that would be laughed at.

Can we use several independent clauses to express an idea of conditional? YES. However, we may face much limitation.

- Give him an inch and he will take a mile.

In this example, the first independent clause conveys the meaning of imperative. If the first independent clause does not convey the meaning of imperative, the whole sentence may be unacceptable.

- Sound in body, sound in mind.

This sentence conveys the meaning of conditional paratactically. However, forms like this may only appear in idioms.

My question:
Can we use several independent clauses to express an idea of conditional without too much limitation? (in certain languages, not limted to English)

Comment: Declerck & Reed (*Conditionals: a Comprehensive Empirical Analysis*, Mouton de Gruyter, 2001) treat these at '11.13 Paratactic Conditionals', pp. 401-407.  I think you are mistaken in calling *Give him an inch* as  an imperative: it does not enjoin the hearer to *give*, it speaks of such a gift by anyone. You may call it a "present subjunctive" if you adhere to certain grammatical sects. I'd just call it an ellipsis. But paratactics with *or* may take an imperative in the condition clause: "Stop or I'll shoot!" They may even take bare NPs in both clauses: "Your money or your life!"

Comment: @StoneyB thank you for your helpful comment

Comment: "Give him an inch and he'll take a mile" is clearly not an imperative. I once published a [paper about these and associated constructions](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/conics.pdf).

Comment: @jlawler: That's a very interesting approach, good paper. But I feel that it doesn't treat the origin of *give* very extensively: it mentions mainly circumstantial evidence and its conclusion that it is from elliptical *if* does not seem definitive. Have you looked at other languages? This construction is very common, and in Dutch, for example, it is clearly an imperative: *geef hem een vinger en hij neemt de hele hand.* (like "Give him an inch and he'll take a yard".) A present subjunctive would be *geve*, but that sounds wrong. The only other option is 1st person sg. with elliptical subject.

Comment: @jlawler Note also that semantic conditionality, and hence a kind of semantic polarity, can be bestowed upon a word or words in many different ways that have no *if*: *good behaviour will be rewarded* (=if the behaviour is good, it will be rewarded). I think conditionality often operates on a higher (pragmatic?) level than the form of an *if* clause.

Comment: @Cerberus: I wasn't trying to account for historical origins; they were as they were and I am innocent of knowledge of, or curiosity about, them. Nor do I know Dutch (I can't hear it in my head fast enough). And I no longer enjoy arguing whether something grammatical "is a" something else grammatical; the devil is always in the presuppositions, and decoding them is tiresome and uninformative at best. As for conditionality, you're talking about modals. Modality (along with negation and quantification) generates operators, with focussed (bound) elements. And ambiguities.

Comment: @jla: All right, then it seems it was a misunderstanding and we don't disagree. As to terminoloy, it may ultimately be trivial, but it does serve to communicate information. If something goes wrong in communication, then terminology may be the cause. When you say *imperative*, I read that as a purely syntactic category, but you seem to be using it in a different, semantic sense. When you say *elliptical*, that makes me think of an historical change, or of a change that occurs in the speaker's mind when he forms a sentence: first he has x y in mind, then he omits y and finally utters only x.

Comment: The imperative construction is a syntactic phenomenon, and it has syntactic tests for distinguishing it. If it didn't, _imperative_ wouldn't mean anything. The paper ran through a number of the tests. Quang Phuc Dong's ["English Sentences Without Overt Grammatical Subject"](http://babel.ucsc.edu/~hank/quangphucdong.pdf) does so also. Ellipsis merely means that something expected is missing.

Comment: Interestingly, in your example _Give him an inch and he will take a mile_, the give-clause does have the structure (but not the meaning) of an imperative in that it is a finite clause with an untensed verb

Comment: @BillJ - easier to see that in a language that actually flexes for person: *Cria cuervos, que te comerán los ojos*, where *cria* cannot be anything else than a sintactical imperative. Or *Fala pouco e bem, ter-te-ão por alguém* vs *não fales muito, ter-te-ão por alguém*, where changing it into the negative requires an inflection that only applies to the imperative mode.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can. Here is an example from English:

- Have you been in an accident? Call our team now on 07123 45678.

That second sentence is only meant to apply if you have been in an accident. Questions and conditionals are related in many interesting ways.

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer to your question, just noting that

> Anyone who should do that would be laughed at

is not a regular conditional! Those "would" or "might" constructions are called counterfactuals, and are semantically not identical to material implication (as it would be the case with "if" sentences or the other kinds that you stated), but - at least in the theories I am aware of - rather have to be analysed with respect to possible worlds (roughly, could we imagine a world hopefully close to ours and in which the consequent is implied by the antecedent if it were true, since (as the name already tells) the antecedents usually are not true in the actual world we are talking about), or possibly by adding some more propositions to the antecedent until the consequent eveutally logically follows from the resulting set of propositions.
In the end, the analysis of "would" will directly or indirectly involve material implication to be interpreted as "if... then", but still, I'd like to have pointed out that this construction is semantically not of the same type as a classical if-statement.

Comment: But such constructions need not be counterfactual, or even tentative or hypothetical: *Anyone who does that will be laughed at*. *Anyone* + the restrictive relative clause is a predication semantically equivalent to a case-specifying condition.

Comment: Hm, yep, you're right. Didn't think of that.

Comment: Please [edit] this to fix all your typos!

Comment: @curiosdannii Could you please specify which typos you mean? Your comments sounds like my post contains a lot of typos, but I only found "impled" and "porpositions" (just fixed them).
Edit: also found "taht" and "sould". Hope it's okay now.

Comment: "In the end, the analysis of "would" will directly or indirectly involve material implication to be interpreted as "if... then". "If  ... then" is not interpreted as material implication, and no theories of 'counterfactuals' present them as material implications.

Comment: @Araucaria Why would "If ... then" not be interprted as material implication, or what what you suggested instead?

Comment: Regarding the second part: I didn't say that counterfactuals are set *equivalent* to material implication, I just said that they will *involve* material implication. This is exactly what is done in e.g. David Lewis' account of counterfactuals involving the concept of similarity (his definition of the would-counterfactual makes direct use of material implication, embedded in his framework with similar worlds) or in Angelika Kratzer's various approaches to counterfactual analysis, whose defintions as well explicitely include implication. Possibly more, those are the ones I know of.

Comment: This is what I am referring to:  1) Lewis (1973): "*p would q*  is true at a world [...] if and only if [...] p -> q holds at every world in S" (where S is a sphre within the system of spheres related to the world). => Lewis, D. (2013). Counterfactuals. John Wiley & Sons. 2) Kratzer (1989): "A 'would'-counterfactual is true if and only if ... the resulting set of propositions logically implies the consequent" (after adding some prepositions to the antecedent in a certain way) => Kratzer, A. (1989). An investigation of the lumps of thought. Linguistics and philosophy, 12(5), 607-653.

Comment: @lemtontree .For a start I don't believe that " if they find  a cure for baldness tomorrow, bald men will be unhappy about it". Now assuming I believe that the chances of them finding a cure for baldness tomorrow is about 1 million to one, I am absolutely barking mad not to believe that conditional - because the odds of it being true are over 1 million to one. Secondly, nobody will ever believe that because the number three is an odd number that [if it is even, it is greater than five], or that [if it is greater than 4 it it less than 3]. But material implication guarantees those to be true.

Comment: I think this is too broad of a topic to discuss in the comment section, maybe we can continue the discussion in chat?

Comment: @lemontree I'm familiar with Lewis and Stalnaker's possible worlds semantics for 'subjunctive' conditionals. However, neither of those involve material implication in any way. Re Kratzer, what she claims (and it is not true) is that according to her model conditionals reduce to material implications *when we have an empty context set*. When this is not the case, they have no material implication-like meanings.

Comment: @lemontree By all means, if you'd like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41303/discussion-between-lemontree-and-araucaria).

Answer (score 0):

In Chinese, certainly. A paratactic vestige from Classical Chinese, it appears in many stock phrases:

```
(1) Dao gao  yi  chi,  mo    gao  yi  zhang.
    dao tall one chi,  devil tall one zhang. (chi and zhang are a traditional Chinese units)
    If (those with the) dao grows taller by a chi, the evil will grow taller by a zhang.
(2) Mei you  Gongchan  Dang,  mei you  Xin Zhongguo.
    Not have Communist Party, not have New China.
    If there were no Communist Party, there would be no New China.
```

These would sound more natural and less literary in normal speech if we add markers like *dehua* or *jiu* ('then'), but they are perfectly acceptable and normal in Classical Chinese.

Comment: P.S. Lest you should wonder, no I'm not from the linguistic division of the fifty cents party... The sentence was discussed a while ago on Language Log: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3340

Comment: I read your sentence examples carefully and think they may be not suitable. The first sentence is just an idiomatic expression, and the second sentence is just like English "no pain, no gain",which is also related to idioms(the form is productive in English). The syntactic property for dehua and jiu may be dubious. You translated jiu into English word then, but I think it may be regarded as a conjunction. By the way, what does " linguistic division of the fifty cents party" mean?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50_Cent_Party)? This term seems derogatory and politically controversial. I think your concern is due to your second example.

Comment: There are other examples in the Language Log link if you're not convinced. I think 'no pain, no gain' cannot be compared to this one because 'no pain' and 'no gain' aren't clauses; 'mei you Gongchan Dang' and 'mei you Xin Zhongguo' are. / Are you sure jiu is a conjunction? I haven't looked deeply, but I don't think its syntactic properties resemble a conjunction at all. I'm fairly sure it's an adverb, judging by its position in the sentence... / Yeah, I was trying my hand at humour :P

Comment: If you want more examples from Classical Chinese, here are some from Pulleyblank (1995): 不奪不饜 (Mencius 1A:1), 不能更鳴，東徙，猶惡子之聲 (Shuoyuan 16.164).